# Understanding the useState and input logic

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, events, use-state

im having trouble to get my UseState to show itself once i click a button, currently i have a function, that that use usestate and show my value on the screen, for example, when i write "miki" in the input box, it will show "miki" on the screen, however, it happens when i click the input box, and i want it to happen when im pressing the button, this is my code untill now:

```
import react, { useState } from "react";

export const ShoppingListPageContainer = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState(``)
    const nameChange = (event) => {
        setName(event.target.value)
    }

    return <div>
        <input label="name: " id="name" onClick={nameChange} />
        <input type="number" name="quantity" />
        <button> Add </button>
        <p> {name} </p>
    </div>
}
```

as u can see, the onClick is on the input and thats why it works when pressing the inputbox, but, when i switch the onClick location to the button, it shows nothing, because there arent any value inserted to the button, obviously, any help?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `onClick` property (in `onClick={nameChange}`). This means your `nameChange` function gets called every time a user clicks into the input box.

You should change this to `onChange={nameChange}` and add the `value={name}` to the input:

```
<input label="name: " id="name" onChange={nameChange} value={name} />
```

This means that the `nameChange` function gets called every time the input changes. The value will also be set to name, so if anything else calls `nameChange`, it will be reflected in the input box.

Comment: and how do i channel this to get to my final result, which is making what i write in the input text box to apear when i click the button

Answer (score 0):

Use the onChange event in the input field. And use the useEffect hook and its dependency to get the current data

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('name', name);
}, [name])
```

```html
<input type="string" onChanhe={(e:any) => nameChange(e.target.value)} />
<p>{name}</p>
```